# How to make a Python Regular Expression, have an optional start requirement?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So I need to be able to check for the word "view" in a sentence, without pulling it out of another word, and even if its the first word.

```
import re


if re.search(r"view", "interview"):
    print "aw"                          #This cuts it out of the word "interview"

if re.search(r" view", "interview"):
    print "aw"                          #This wont cut it out of another word, but 
                                    #doesn't work if "view" is the first word.

if re.search(r" view", "view"):
    print "aw"                          #This just shows it wont work since its the first word.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Mind providing your input and expected output (including cases where your current code fails)?

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but it sounds like you are looking for word boundaries, or `\b`

Comment: `r"(^|\s)view(\s|$)"` perhaps? Its either at the start of the line or preceded by space. Same with end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for **`word boundaries`**, or `\b` when using regular expressions:

Try using `\bview\b` as your regular expression.  `\b` will match `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`, so it will only match the standalone word `view`, and not when it is found inside another word.

Here are some examples:

```
rgx = r'\bview\b'

print(re.search(rgx, 'interview'))
print(re.search(rgx, 'view is the first word'))
print(re.search(rgx, ' view is after a space'))

# None
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='view'>
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 5), match='view'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "view at the start of the string" case can only happen once per string so you can check that individually. That can be done by using one `if` check, or simpler, just add a space before the target string. For example check for `"view"` in `str`:

`if re.search(" view", " " + str): print("Found!")`

Answer (score 0):

The occurrence can be at beginning, end and in the middle and hence we try to capture all such occurrences while ignoring the ones where it occurs as part of other text.

```
re.search(r"(^view)|(\sview$)|(\sview\s)"," view interview is view")
```

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx captures every Word which has "view" somewhere inside it.

```
/([A-z]*view[A-z]*)/gi
```